# How can I run `git commit` and `git push` in atom?

Tags: atom-editor

Is there a way to run `git commit` and `git push` in the Atom editor?

I read this blog post but could not find that mentioned: http://blog.atom.io/2014/03/13/git-integration.html

Answer (score 82, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [git-plus](https://atom.io/packages/git-plus) package. Install that - it provides full Git integration with commands like `commit`, `add`, `push`, `pull` and lots of others.

[image: Git-Plus]

Comment: After installing this how do I use this ?

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya Press 'Ctrl+Shift+H' and you'll get a palette with all the commands provided by git-plus. ('Cmd+Shift+H' if you're using OSX)

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya The commands are also available from the Packages->Git-plus menu

Comment: how do you open that terminal looking thing where you type in "git wr"  and "git com" @nwinkler

Comment: @Drmjo you've found this out by now for sure but it's `ctrl` (or `cmd` on mac) + `shift` + `P`

Comment: Use `ctrl` + `(` to open up the git tab in atom

Answer (score 62):

There've been some developments since this question was initially asked. Both `git commit` and `git push` (along with lotsa other commands) are now available in the app natively (version 1.18+).

There is a GUI for staging and reviewing changes as well as committing them with a commit message.

[image]

Just double-click to stage or un-stage files. Clicking on a file in Atom's Git GUI will load up the colored diff for reviewing changes. Type in a commit message right there in the text entry box and click the button to make the commit! Commit title's with message bodies (just a new line separating them) is supported - there's even a counter to let you know when your git commit message title is getting too long.

Also, when you have a change that's been staged and committed, you can push the contribution to your GitHub repository by pushing the down/up arrows at the bottom right to load up the options:

[image]

...then selecting the "Push" option:

[image]

Up goes your commits to the cloud!

See: https://github.atom.io/

Note as well that there is a branch display which can be used to switch branches or create new ones. Also, you can do pulls and fetching.

---

To stage new files and changes, and make a commit you also can access the `git` tools from either the Packages Tab:

[image]

... or the View Tab:

[image]

A push will, of course, require your username and password.

Also, setting up the GitHub preview requires authentication:

[image]

---

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> opens the "Git" pane
...and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> will close it.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> opens the "GitHub(preview)" pane
...and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> will close it.

[One way to configure `git`](https://github.com/atom/github/issues/932#issuecomment-317802161) so you can bypass manually entering your username and password while using these Atom features:

1. Set your Git user info in the .gitconfig file.
2. On Windows this is usually located in your Users folder.

   Example: If your username was Bob, your .gitconfig should be in: C:\Users\Bob.gitconfig
3. If this file doesn't exist, you need to create it and fill it out as followed:
4. (fill in the name and email part and save)

   [user]
       name = {NAME}
       email = {EMAIL}

See also: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: Brilliant! Should be the accepted answer because it doesn't require additional packages to be installed. Thanks

Comment: I have 2 remotes set up. I want to specify which remote to push to. Can I do that in Atom? I don't see how to  do it directly from the GUI. Or do I need an additional package?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a git GUI package: [git-control](https://atom.io/packages/git-control). It is easier to use and there is a small display of auto generated git commands, which is very helpful for beginners to get a good idea about git and version control.

[image: git control package from Atom.io]

Answer (score 0):

There's also one more nice sweet package for commits: [`git-commit`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160914024920/https://atom.io/packages/git-commit).

Good news: it's super quick to commit all your stuff.

Bad news: it doesn't support pushing.

[image]
<sub>(source: [github-camo.com](https://i.github-camo.com/555ebe63fde6a174e40706d272df277ae9b9c2a0/68747470733a2f2f6769746875622e636f6d2f616c616e7a616e617474616465762f61746f6d2d6769742d636f6d6d69742f626c6f622f6d61737465722f6769742d636f6d6d69742d73637265656e73686f742e706e673f7261773d74727565))</sub>

Comment: push can be added on post-commit, nice when working alone

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the process more automatic, I have switched to another strategy to avoid having to click on too many buttons (am I lazy or it is [worth the time](https://xkcd.com/1205/)?).

The idea is to create a small `Makefile` file at the root of your project which would contain something like:

```
default: git

git:
    git commit -am'Atom edits'
    git push
```

I am then using the excellent [build-make](https://atom.io/packages/build-make) package to run that two commands in one key stroke `<Cmd>-<Alt>-B` in my case.